# При удалении элементов выскакивает IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, list, arraylist, while

написал код для удаления элемента последующих элементов из списка по индексу.

```
public void deletеElementAndNextElements(String string) {
    int indexOf = stringList.indexOf(string);
    do {
        stringList.remove(indexOf);
    } while (!stringList.get(indexOf).isEmpty());
```

Выскакивает ошибка

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
```

Что я не так делаю

Comment: Вы удалили последний элемент и потом пытаетесь взять его по индексу в условии `!stringList.get(indexOf).isEmpty()`. Попробуйте поменять условие на `stringList.size() > indexOf`. Кстати, посмотрите ещё в сторону метода `subList()` интерфейса `List` - с его помощью то же можно сделать проще.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сама по себе ошибка это выход за пределы массива

Можно так

```
    public static void deletеElementAndNextElements(String string) {

        int indexOf = stringList.indexOf(string);
        //если такая строка в списке не найдела то выходим
        if(indexOf == -1)
            return;
        while(stringList.size() > indexOf){
            stringList.remove(stringList.size()-1);
        }
    }
```

или так

```
 public static void deletеElementAndNextElements(String string) {

    int indexOf = stringList.indexOf(string);

    //если такая строка в списке не найдела то выходим
    if(indexOf == -1)
        return;

    List<String> sublist = stringList.subList(indexOf,stringList.size());
    stringList.removeAll(sublist);
}
```